# How to assign values to variables in SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, variables, select, stored-procedures, declare

I'm trying to create a variable that indicates how much of a product is left in inventory, but in visual studio it alerts several values are being assigned to the varialvel @quantityProduct, could anyone help me?

```
BEGIN
Declare @quantityProduct int
Select * from tbStore
Where name = @product
Set @quantityProduct = (select (quantity) from tbStore)
END
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Your example is not "SQL" it's some kind of procedural extension to the SQL query language.

Comment: Your script appears to do three things, declare a variable as an INTEGER, SELECT all the rows from a table where the name matches a variable that I assume is declared when the stored procedure calls (noting that these won't go anywhere), sets the value of the variable to EVERY quantity in the table.  I think you need to combine steps 2 and 3 together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
BEGIN
Declare @quantityProduct int
Select @quantityProduct = quantity
from tbStore
Where name = @product
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so:

```
Declare @quantityProduct int
Select @quantityProduct = quantity 
From tbStore
Where name = @product
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare it as int. Your query possibly returns more than one values, therefore the result cannot be stored in this variable. Limit your query to return only one value or declare your variable as a table of int.